# Update Preview of the new UI doesn't work in Chrome and IE (but works in Firefox)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have configured the new UI for a Java web site and everything works fine, but only if I use Firefox as browser. When using Chrome or Internet Explorer, the Update Preview feature doesn't work properly.

When I create a new page it creates the page directly (not the temporary file) and does not display the page but remains as 'Loading'.

Have you experience something like this?any clues in order to fix this issue?Thanks!

Comment: Have you already reached out to SDL Customer Support with this problem? They might know more about it and the support channel is definitely more suited for this type of troubleshooting than Stack Overflow..

Comment: Frank, indeed, I have just open a ticket to Customer Support, I was just wondering if any of you have seen this before.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't ring a bell. Definitely check the JavaScript console of Firefox/Firebug for errors and check the how the data flow between client and server is different with Firefox than with the working browsers.

Comment: Firefox is the browser that does work though.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The approach to trouble shooting remains the same though. Compare the JavaScript console and data flow between a browser that works and one that doesn't.

Comment: It's just a hunch, but when we have things that work on FF but not on IE/Chrome, it is often related to the internet settings (e.g. proxy server). IE and Chrome both use the same settings, FF manages its own. Could this somehow be related?

Comment: We have been working further in this issue and found out that UI works with Chrome if the TOMCAT contains a ROOT folder...also if this folder is empty we receive a 404 error as it tries to find a se_blank.html. any of you have seen this before? any ideas how to configured this feature so the TOMCAT does not need a ROOT folder?

Comment: That's good info to update your question with, Emma. I'll post an answer based on this update.

Answer (score 2):

You can [prevent 404 errors on your Staging site](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_2F3D125DF7274CC9BE33BBBDC284D314) by literally creating that se_blank.html file (which can be an empty page) in the root folder.

Also see more info on [session preview configuration](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_8E80718DD9834A418F8D818F30F518F6). Specifically, there's a [web.xml setting](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_30B39307D70A4380AE5AB159BC3F374E) that might apply if you have a subdirectory for your site. Use `/*` if it's at the root, otherwise set it to the path that contains your staging Web site.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Binary Content Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```